# Python sorting of list

Tags: python

I have an input file -  file.txt :

guten 
('nine', 'november') 
('six', 'nine') 
0 
end

My python program is:

```
aa = []
with open('file.txt', 'r') as F1:
    for line in F1:
       line = line.rstrip('\n')
       aa.append(line)
    print aa
```

I am getting the output as:

```
['guten', "('nine', 'november')", "('six', 'nine')", '0', 'end', '']
```

But my expected output is:

```
['guten', ('nine', 'november'), ('six', 'nine'), '0', 'end', '']
```

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong ? Your help will be useful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain precisely, what rules you want to use to sort the data, and what rules you want to use to interpret the input? It seems you want lines that are enclosed in `()` in the text file to turn into tuples, even though that text file is not Python code? But you want numbers to stay as strings?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have modified the question. I want this output so that I can sort and get the final result. Can u help me ??

Comment: try running this `sorted(['b', 'a', 'f', 'd', 'e', (3, 4), 1, 4, 5])`

Comment: Your expected output doesn't seem to sort the input at all. Are you really looking for a way to turn the strings on lines 2 and 3 into tuples?

Comment: Sort, but what criteria?

Comment: Yea, and I want my output to be in this format ['guten', ('nine', 'november'), ('six', 'nine'), '0', 'end', '']

Comment: @Marcin That's the point I'm trying to make. OP has not supplied a criteria for sorting

Comment: To give an only slightly silly answer, `print "['', '0', 'end', 'guten', ('nine', 'november'), ('six', 'nine')]"` That gives the output you want, but I'm guessing it's not the answer you're looking for! We need a clear description of what you want the program to do beyond producing this single output for this single input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I can't really imagine how this would be useful, the following will do what you're asking for  (given the limited data in the file you've given us):

```
import ast
aa = []
with open('file.txt', 'r') as F1:
    for line in F1:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        if line.startswith('('):
            aa.append(ast.literal_eval(line))  # turn tuple strings into tuples
        else:
            aa.append(line)       
    print aa
```